Series diode to reduce charging voltage, BUT with a twist
I have been agonising over this question for a number of days, and I cannot come up with a simple answer.
I have some (nominal) 48 V, 15 kW (16S) battery packs that obviously need charging. I purchased some “smart chargers” that detect the voltage of the pack before they turn on and start charging at  58.4 V @ 20 A, AND they are potted (so no tinkering). I have set up an ESP32 to read the Enphase gateway to determine when I am exporting, and up to 4 chargers are energised through DIN rail contactors to reduce the solar export bit by bit by turning on the chargers one at a time.
The problem is that I don't want to charge the LiFePo4 cells to 3.65 V (58.4 V) and thought a high power diode in series would work to reduce the voltage reaching the packs by “If”. The problem is that the chargers don't “see” any voltage because of the diodes, and therefore don't start. Is there a circuit anybody can conjure up that fixes this.
I was thinking of this diode Mouser No:844-70HF10  Mfr. No:VS-70HF10  Mfr.:Vishay
Thanks in advance.

having tried the exact same thing before, i can say "no", this won't work. As the current drops, so does the voltage dropped through the diode, so by the time it's done, there's basically no power/voltage lost through the diode. If you did use several to get it to stop charging early, it will never fill the batteries completely. you might try a resistor across the diode to fool the charger, maybe a 10k - 100k; that shouldn't be too much current to piss off the BMS with the high but powerless "trickle" leakage voltage.

DanDavis.... thanks! I was thinking of the resistor idea, but, in series with the reverse diode. Now that you have cleared that up, I'll try the resistor. I'm assuming 1/4 - 1/2W would work OK. Can you suggest a better diode selection?

You could use two diodes in anti-parallel configuration to provide a voltage drop without rectification.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Be aware that the voltage across a diode depends upon the current flowing through it. If a diode is used to "fool" a charger, but the charger provides a "float" charge (which is acceptable for LiFePO4 cells) then the terminal voltage of the battery may creep up above the V-0.6 or V-0.7 you intend.

The charger design is this. It "confirms" that a battery is connected, then starts charging to 58.4V. Then it shuts off when that voltage is achieved. It was a bad purchase on my behalf. There is no float fallback setting, and no adjustments.
My main concern is that I don't want to rely on the BMS settings to be the last line of defence. It's considered bad form for charging LiPo batteries.
The reverse diode would also drop the voltage that the charger "sees". I can't get my head around it
